# Multiple per-user services on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: windows-service, windows-server-2022

We just upgraded a couple of servers to Windows Server 2022. I am noticing in the Services Control Panel, a number of services which present multiple instances, presumably one instance for every user context logged in to the server. See screenshot below. (I've also verified that this behavior appears in Windows Server 2019.) I'm trying to find out more information about this. The reason this is a problem for me is because I am monitoring our servers for security purposes and I am receiving alerts every time these services are "installed" or "uninstalled" which presumably occurs every time a user logs in or logs out.

If there is a defined list of these services, I can exclude them from monitoring by wildcard. e.g. CaptureService_*. Thanks for your advice!

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows

Comment: @joeqwerty Thank you very much! Exactly the reference I need. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept that to your credit.

Comment: that's a normal behavior due it has User specific setting